# Why isn't Closure Compiler warning about violations of @package visibility?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

When I use the `@package` annotation and then try to access it from a file in another directory I receive no warning on compiling. The compiler is given a warning_level argument of `'VERBOSE'` (and I receive warnings for @private violations).

See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

For example:

In `ns/pkg/foo.js`

```
/**
* @constructor
*/
ns.pkg.Foo = function(){}

/**
* @package
*/
ns.pkg.Foo.prototype.modify = function() {}
```

In `ns/view.js`

```
/**
* Factory method
*/
ns.View.create = function() {
    var myFoo = new ns.pkg.Foo();
    myFoo.modify(); // ***no compiler error***
    //...
}
```

Am I missing a compiler flag or misunderstanding closure docs? Or is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Did you turn on the visibility warning guard? You can do that either with `--warning_level=VERBOSE` or `--jscomp_warning=visibility`.